# Restore Tensorflow model on docker

Tags: docker, tensorflow

I am using a face recognition model based on tensorflow. in my local machine - ubuntu 14.04 - everything works.
when I deploy it using docker, I am getting the following error:

```
DataLossError: Unable to open table file /data/model/model.ckpt-80000: Data loss: not an sstable (bad magic number): perhaps your file is in a different file format and you
need to use a different restore operator?
```

I am using python implementation for tensorflow.
The model is in the old 11.* format (model.meta & model.ckpt-80000) while the tensorflow python version is 12.* . It shouldn't be a problem, as that's the configuration in my local machine, as well as in the place where I took the model from.
The versions of tensorflow, numpy and protobuf are identical in my machine and in the docker machine.

Any advice?

---

### UPDATE

I created a small script that runs perfectly on my machine. Then, I run the same script on the deployed on virtual machine (AWS instance) BUT NOT on docker. It also failed, with the same error.
The deployed machine is ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like i was dealing with a corrupted file